# class data returning null after being set

Tags: java, android

I have a class that I assign string values through standard get/set methods. After setting the values it returns them as expected. When I call the class values in another fragment they return null. I can't seem to figure it out.

How I set up the class and set the values.

```
public class BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View view
    public static Store_Model store_model = null;
    ...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic_info, container, false);
    ...
    zipCode = zip.getText().toString();        
    // set info        
    store_model = new Store_Model();
    store_model.setZip(zipCode);
    Log.v("STORE" , "Zip: " + store_model.getZip());
    ...
```

The Log.v prints out: "Zip: 47564" exactly as expected. However when I call the class in another fragment like this it gives me an error.

```
public class Options_ListFragment extends ListFragment {
    View view;
    public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;
    ....
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_options, container, false);
    Log.v("STORE", "Zip: " + store_model.getZip()); <!--- ERROR
```

As noted in the code, trying to pull that value is giving me a null pointer exception. I do not understand how this class is losing its values. Maybe I just need another pair of eyes. Thanks for the help in advance

**Edit**

Thanks @Juan Jose Fidalgo and @SJuan76. I figured it out and I changed my code to the following in Options_ListFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_options, container, false);       
        if (BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model != null) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.assets_store_info);
            ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            store = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.store);
            phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
            city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city);
            zip = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zip);
            state = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.state);

            getStoreInfo();
        }

public void getStoreInfo() {
        String mStore = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getStoreNum();
        String mPhone = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getPhoneNum();
        String mAddress = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getAddress();
        String mCity = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getCity();
        String mZip = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getZip();
        String mState = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getState();

        store.setText("Store #: " + mStore);
        phone.setText("Phone #: " + mPhone);
        address.setText("Address: " + mAddress);
        city.setText("City: " + mCity);
        zip.setText("Zip: " + mZip);
        state.setText("State: " + mState);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two variables. One as attribute in `BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment`, the other as attribute in `Option_ListFragment`. They are completely different variables.

If you have a reference to the `BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment` instance (lets call it `biaf`) in the `Option_ListFragment`, you can reference its view attribute as `biaf.storeModel`, and that will give what you want.

Best practice is to make `storeModel` private and add a `getStoreModel()` method to the `BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment`. Also, try to follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: So you're saying that 
`public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;` and then calling `store_model.getZip();` is not the same as 
`BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model.getZip();`?

Comment: You are assigning the value at a time in which the original reference still is null. When you later change the first variable, the second one does not get changed.

Answer (score 1):

The fragment

```
Options_ListFragment
   public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;
```

is executed before than

```
BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.onCreateView(...)
```

For this reason, when,

```
public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;
```

is executed, the variable

```
BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model
```

contains null value. So,

```
Options_ListFragment
  public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;
```

get a null value.

The fragment

```
 Options_ListFragment
   public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;
```

is executed when the class Options_ListFragment is loaded by ClassLoader the first time that the class Options_ListFragment is invoked in any place of your code. You should look when Options_ListFragment is invoked.

Comment: Actually the way it works is, You fill out the information in BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment, then when you return to Options_ListFragment and if BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model != null then it will execute, however it is always returning null. So it is never executing.

Comment: Because, "public static Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;", is executed when Class<Options_ListFragment> is loaded by class loader. Probably if you change this line by  "public Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;" it could works fine, because removing the static modifier the fragment "public Store_Model store_model = BasicInfo_Assets_Fragment.store_model;" will not be executed until a instance of Options_ListFragment is created.